# IgApiClient - IgNotFoundError in DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Well, when running the bot the console leaves an error that the user of the USERID variable was not found. The rest of the code is fine I guess. Here is the code

```js
const {IgApiClient} = require('instagram-private-api');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const TOKEN = '';
const USERINSTAGRAM = '';
const PASSINSTAGRAM = '';
const CHANNEL = '';
const USERID = '';

async function main() {
    const ig = new IgApiClient();
    ig.state.generateDevice(USERINSTAGRAM);
    await ig.account.login(USERINSTAGRAM, PASSINSTAGRAM);
    const client = new Client({
        intents: [
            GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        ],
    });
    await client.login(TOKEN);
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL);
    let lastPostID;
    const feed = ig.feed.user(USERID);
    const posts = await feed.items();
    if (posts.length > 0) {
        lastPostID = posts[0].id;
    }
    setInterval(async () => {
        const posts = await feed.items();
        if (posts.length > 0 && posts[0].id !== lastPostID) {
            lastPostID = posts[0].id;
            channel.send(`El usuario ha publicado un nuevo post en Instagram: ${posts[0].code}`);
            await sendPost(ig, channel, posts);
        }
    }, 60 * 1000); // 1 minuto 
    }

    main();
```

and here is the terminal error msg:

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\core\request.js:103
> return new errors_1.IgNotFoundError(response);
> ^
>
> IgNotFoundError: GET /api/v1/feed/user/xxxxx/ - 404 Not Found;
> at Request.handleResponseError (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\core\request.js:103:20)
> at Request.send (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\core\request.js:54:28)
> at async UserFeed.request (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\feeds\user.feed.js:21:26)
> at async UserFeed.items (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\instagram-private-api\dist\feeds\user.feed.js:31:22)
> at async main (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bot\pruebagit.js:26:19)
> Node.js v18.15.0

The user is well written, is not a private account and has a post in their feed